# using Exchange Web Service API

Tags: exchangewebservices

Working on a project using exchange web service API, but I want to confirm this before proceeding. with the API, the code need to explicitly specify the exchange version like this:

```
var exchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password),
        };
```

so my question is when the exchange server is upgraded to say exchange 2013, would the code still work?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this will still work.

EWS schemas are backward- and forward-compatible. The schema you specify above determines the features which will be available to your application. If your application targets an earlier version then what your connected to then it just means you wont be able take advantage of the new features.

See following for more information..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190904(v=exchg.150).aspx (Search for section on EWS Client Features)

Answer (score 0):

Exchange2010_SP2 is valid for Future service packs like Service pack3